# Can I get Visual Studio to debug Debug builds (C#/.NET) with Just My Code enabled and Release builds with it disabled?

Tags: c#, debugging, release

I'm finding that whenever I switch back and forth from debugging Debug builds to Release builds (which at the moment I'm doing a lot because I'm curious about how well the optimizer did, including cases where it's *too* good and big chunks of unit tests disappear entirel in Release) I have to manually switch Tools / Options / Debugging / General / Enable Just My Code on and off. This is starting to feel tedious.

I'm wondering if there's a way to change debug options automatically in the two configurations? Or if I'm holding something wrong?

Comment: Hard to make sense of this.  Set breakpoints to inspect the code of interest, don't single-step to it.